# Possible duplicate graphs for education/dev-type in 2016 survey

Tags: bug, survey, survey-2016

## Same exact graphs for 3 categories

It just seems strange for the following graphs to have the *same data*... Is this really the case?

**Online learning**

[image: online]

**Masters degree**

[image: masters]

**Doctorate**

[image: doctorate]

---

## Same dev types (and order) on last category

I noticed the *same types and order* listed for Industry cert as well, which does not match the summary description:

> Enterprise Level Services Developers are most likely to have completed
>   an Industry certification program (iOS Mobile Devs are least likely).

[image: industry-cert]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, there are some issues in what you are seeing. That's because it's not ready for public viewing.  It was an error to have this out, at this time, and we've pulled it for the time-being.

We're still working through the data and hope to have it available next week.

Comment: I was wondering how people found this, considering I hadn't seen an announcement that it had been released.

Comment: Let's just say there was a bug in the code to display it. The bug has been squashed.

Comment: @CodyGray I found it on Hacker News earlier today.